# Docker output not visible in browser

Tags: python, docker, web-applications, dockerfile, streamlit

I am trying to build a docker image for `streamlit` app. `Docker` build is successful but the output is not visible in the browser.

**Dockerfile Code:**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
EXPOSE 8501
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN git clone https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit-example.git .

ADD requirements.txt .
ADD streamlit_ap.py .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "streamlit_ap.py", "--server.port=8501","--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

**Docker output:**

docker run streamlit

Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

URL: http://0.0.0.0:8501

**The output of streamlit is not visible at** "http://0.0.0.0:8501" and http://localhost:8501/

Browser Output:
[image]

Comment: ADD streamlit_ap.py . missed `p` word  `ADD streamlit_app.py .` and i prefer use `COPY . .` instead 2 ADD

Comment: Try `docker run -p 8501:8501 streamlit`

Comment: It is executing and generated one URL. The output Url displays the following statement.
This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

following changes in the docker file and docker run help me to generate the expected output.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
EXPOSE 8501
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN git clone https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit-example.git .

ADD requirements.txt .
ADD streamlit_ap.py .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["streamlit_ap.py"]
```

Docker Build command:

```
docker build -t my_app .
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 my_app
```

Thanks to "JacekK" for your valuable suggestion.